# If anonymous and anonymously are words, and so is onymous - why isn't onymously?

Tags: orthography

I need to write the following but apparently "onymously" isn't a word?...

```
The user can post anonymously or onymously
```

How can anonymously be ok to use - but not onymously? Can anyone suggest a suitable alternative for my sentence?

Comment: I agree with James that it is a word. However, it is a word that one almost never encounters and that could be a reason to choose an alternative. I would suggest something in the lines of: "the user can post,  anonymously or not"

Comment: Thanks @PeterH. I guess I like to sound clever in my proposals, so might stick with onymously! Hopefully it's obvious what it means in the context of that sentence.

Comment: @benjaminhull I normally caution against being "too clever" but in this case, I think the meaning is perfectly clear in the context and so (hopefully) more people will think "nice word!" than "huh?"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by "not a word". **Onymously** is a word formed by the usual rules of English morphology, and consistent with English phonology. The meaning can readily be determined from its formation. So that definitely makes it a word. (The meaning is not immediately obvious to me, because I have never come across **onymous** before, either. But I guess I would figure it out, especially in the context of your example sentence. Which is fine as it is, by the way.)

If by "not a word" you mean "not in the dictionary" then [MW shows it as the adverbial form of onymous](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/onymous).

Comment: Yes, I guess that's what I meant: why is it not in the dictionary. I had assumed unless it's in the dictionary that it's not a word you can use. Thank you for enlightening me.

Comment: Dictionaries record the language: they don't set it. Since language changes, all dictionaries are out of date somewhere in their contents.

Comment: No dictionary lists all the words in the English language, not even "unabridged" ones.  And when a word's meaning can be easily determined by applying, to a listed word, the rules for prefixes and suffixes, a dictionary is more likely to omit it.

Comment: It's worth flagging up the full OED definition here: **onymous** - *Having a name, named; (of a writing) bearing the name of the author; (of an author) that gives his or her name.* After which they make the "usage note" *Usually explicitly contrasted with **anonymous.*** It's not a common usage, but given that context it would always be easy to understand. Personally I'd be more inclined to describe it as a "facetious back-formation" likely to be repeatedly and independently "re-coined" as circumstances require, rather than "a word" as such.

Comment: I'd also point out that if it *were* to become a "well-established" term, the non-negated version would very likely be ***nonymous*** (cf ***anion, anhydrous,*** etc.). To the extent that the usage has had any traction at all over the past couple of centuries, that's been the dominant version, as shown by [this NGram.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=onymous%2Cnonymous&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Conymous%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cnonymous%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: @FumbleFingers I don't quite get your point. We have **anhydrous** vs **hydrous** (not nyhdrous). And while an anion is negative (electrically) it is not the negated form of ion (the opposite of anion is cation); but if it were, we would have **anion** vs **ion** (not nion). So I don't see where you get "nonymous" from. The Greek root is onyma and that seems to have been preserved in the back-formation from anonymous to onymous.

Comment: @James: I should have extended the date range of my NGram link back another century. It clearly shows that 200-300 years ago (when the non-negated form did at least have *some* currency) it was nearly always ***nonymous***. And as a native speaker myself, I think it just "feels natural"  to transfer the **/n/** to the quirkily innovative back-formation. Perhaps precisely *because* it's quirky, implying that it needs a bit of emphasis to make sure the listener realises he should pay attention to grasp the intended sense.

Comment: ...in support of my "facetious back-formation" claim, I'll just say that the full OED's first cite for ***anonymous*** is 1601. But what some people might think of as the "root" form ***onymous*** doesn't appear until nearly two centuries later, in 1775. OED don't actually list ***nonymous***, but my NGram strongly suggests they should have.

Answer (score 2):

***Onymously*** has an entry in the OED, though it is stated to be *rare*.

> With a person's name given or stated; by name.
>
> 1800   W. Taylor in J. W. Robberds Mem. W. Taylor (1843) I. 346   The
>   impropriety of using author's names in public journals, when speaking
>   of writings not onomously claimed.
>
> 1889   V. Horsley in S. Paget Sir Victor Horsley (1919) 86   He
>   anonymously or onymously is not worth powder and shot.